# Can't resolve local DNS without modifying /etc/resolv.conf

Tags: networking, server, dns

I have a local DNS server at 10.0.0.1 with some entries that aren't fully qualified, ie `server1` resolves to `10.0.0.2`.
On an Ubuntu 20.04 server, I have my /etc/netplan config pointing to 10.0.0.1 for DNS.

However, I can't seem to resolve `server1` unless I modify my /etc/resolv.conf to include `nameserver 10.0.0.1`. My understanding was that /etc/resolv.conf was not made to be modified manually, so I don't think this is the correct solution (it gets overwritten anyways).

I checked from a Windows machine, and it seemed to be able to resolve `server1` with no issues. And as I mentioned, Ubuntu *can* resolve the name, just only if I modify /etc/resolv.conf
I suspect this has to do with the fact that /etc/resolv.conf just has 127.0.0.53 as an entry, but I'm sure there's a good reason for that.

Is this expected behavior for Ubuntu, or is there some other way I can get local DNS resolution working? My /etc/netplan looks like this

```
network:
    ethernets:
        ens4:
            addresses:
            - 10.0.0.22/24
            dhcp4: false
            gateway4: 10.0.0.1
            nameservers:
                addresses: [10.0.0.1]

    version: 2
```

Comment: When you use nslookup, it will show you where it is looking. Check the other folders for config files (/run/netplan and /lib/netplan) for conflict? I notice no 'renderer' directive, as in here: https://linuxconfig.org/netplan-network-configuration-tutorial-for-beginners ...don't forget to run 'netplan generate' after. Also ref: https://netplan.io/reference/#common-properties-for-all-device-types

Comment: What does `resolvectl --status` show for your DNS servers?  ResolveD handles the initial stub resolution in your system for DNS.  Also check what `resolvectl query server1` says

Comment: I suggest that you amend `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: `resolvectl status` seems to show what I would expect based on the netplan config. This was also after I added a `renderer: networkd` line to my netplan and rebooting
 ` Current DNS Server: 10.0.0.1`
  ` DNS Servers: 10.0.0.1 8.8.8.8`